# Which file defines the virtual console color

Tags: kernel, source

I am trying to find the source in the Ubuntu kernel tree that defines color values for the virtual console.

Where is it defined? 
On other linux distributions, it is defined in `drivers/char/vt.c`

Answer (score 0):

Found it:
Located in `/drivers/tty/vt/vt.c`

http://kernel.ubuntu.com/git/ubuntu/ubuntu-trusty.git/tree/drivers/tty/vt/vt.c